# How to use SPARQL UPDATE UNLOAD to delete data from aws Neptune db

Tags: amazon-web-services, sparql, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I want to use the UNLOAD command for unloading the data (.ttl file) in Neptune graph db.

I tried by also by curl command in jupyter lab python terminal from neptune graph db. Could anyone please give example how to use UNLOAD command? Using this documentation :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/sparql-api-reference-unload.html

```
%%sparql
UNLOAD <https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/folder-name/file.ttl> FROM GRAPH <http://aws.amazon.com/neptune/vocab/v01/DefaultNamedGraph>
```

AND also

```
!curl https://cluster-endpoint:8182/sparql \
\-d "update=UNLOAD <https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/folder-name/file.ttl>"
```

In both cases it is showing me HTTP connect timeout while loading from s3...

Comment: Did you use a pre-signed S3 URL? In your example it looks like you just used the bucket name and prefix.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your answer. It already worked before with pre-signed s3 URL. foreg: [UNLOAD "pre-signed s3 url generated"]

Comment: I have tested with both public and pre-signed S3 files, all appears to be working as expected. I have also tested the "FROM GRAPH" and "INTO GRAPH" features, and all seem to work as expected as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Charles could you please show me how you are doing with public s3 files directly without pre-signed??

Comment: While it is usually not recommended to have a public bucket, there are numerous ways to do so. A quick search for me came up with this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/